# Placing a cost raster in Arcmap Table of Contents in 10.2.2

Tags: raster, arcmap, arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, c#

We have a set of routines that have been used for writing rasters to the ArcMap table of contents from our tools.  The code that always worked is this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Used for testing only.  Do not execute this in published server code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rasterDataset"></param>
    /// <param name="layerName"></param>
    internal static void PutToMap(IGeoDataset rasterDataset, string layerName)
    {
        if (rasterDataset == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("rasterDataset");
        }
        RasterLayer layer = new RasterLayer();
        IApplication baseApp = (IApplication)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriFramework.AppRef"));
        IMxDocument doc = (IMxDocument)(baseApp.Document);

        IMap activeMap = doc.ActiveView.FocusMap;
        if (rasterDataset is Raster)
        {
            layer.CreateFromDataset(((IRaster2)(Raster)rasterDataset).RasterDataset);
        }
        else
        {
            layer.CreateFromDataset((RasterDataset) rasterDataset);
        }
        layer.Name = layerName;
        layer.Visible = true;
        activeMap.AddLayer(layer);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used for testing only.  Do not execute this in published server code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="layer">The raster layer or subclass that will be displayed</param>
    /// <param name="layerName">The name to be put in the TOC</param>
    internal static void PutToMap(IRasterLayer layer, string layerName)
    {
        IApplication baseApp = (IApplication)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriFramework.AppRef"));
        IMxDocument doc = (IMxDocument)(baseApp.Document);

        IMap activeMap = doc.ActiveView.FocusMap;

        layer.Name = layerName;
        layer.Visible = true;
        activeMap.AddLayer(layer);
    }

    internal static void PutToMap(IRaster raster, string layername)
    {
        IRasterLayer layer = new RasterLayerClass();
        layer.CreateFromRaster(raster);
        PutToMap(layer, layername);
    }
```

We are now trying to debug a problem but when I try to write the cost raster out, these methods return an error when I try getting the singleton for ArcRef.  The Activator.CreateInstance throws an exception in trying to load the module.  Has anyone done this in 10.2.2 and is there a way to get things running that I'm missing???

I have tried changing the CreateInstance from Type.GetTypeFromProgID to Type.GetTypeFromCLSID and both approaches throws an exception.  It returns an error of 8000ffff or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a bit of work with a fellow geo programmer we found a workaround to this new ESRI issue.

Where we are creating and instance and casting it to IApplication, we now set the IApplication to this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This replaces the broken ESRI process of Activator.CreateInstance for AppRef
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static IApplication GetRunningObject()
    {
        IAppROT appRot = new AppROTClass(); 
        for (int index = 0; index < appRot.Count; index++)
        {
            if (appRot.get_Item(index) is ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.AppRef)
                return (IApplication)appRot.get_Item(index);
        }
        return null;
    }
```